# WPF Validation on Binding - ComboBox SelectedItem won't validate

Tags: wpf, validation, binding

I tried to write my own Validation rule for a ComboBox, the rule is attached to the binding for SelectedItem - However it dosn't work.  I've got similar rules working on the Text property ...

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
        <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
            <Binding Path="Animal">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validators:ComboBoxValidationRule ErrorMessage="Please select an animal" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I think its down to the code I'm using to call the validation which I found on the net.  Basically SelectedItem isn't coming up a dependency property.

It itterates through dependencyPropertyFields which contains TextProperty and SelectionBoxItemProperty but no SelectedItemProperty.

```
private void ValidateBindings(DependencyObject element)
    {
        Type elementType = element.GetType();

        FieldInfo[] dependencyPropertyFields = elementType.GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);


        // Iterate over all dependency properties
        foreach (FieldInfo dependencyPropertyField in dependencyPropertyFields)
        {
            DependencyProperty dependencyProperty =
                dependencyPropertyField.GetValue(element) as DependencyProperty;

            if (dependencyProperty != null)
            {


                Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(element, dependencyProperty);


                BindingExpression bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(element, dependencyProperty);

                // Issue 1822 - Extra check added to prevent null reference exceptions
                if (binding != null && bindingExpression != null)
                {


                    // Validate the validation rules of the binding
                    foreach (ValidationRule rule in binding.ValidationRules)
                    {
                        ValidationResult result = rule.Validate(element.GetValue(dependencyProperty),
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                        bindingExpression.UpdateSource();

                        if (!result.IsValid)
                        {
                            ErrorMessages.Add(result.ErrorContent.ToString());
                        }

                        IsContentValid &= result.IsValid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyway know where I'm going wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't finding the [SelectedItemProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditemproperty.aspx), because ComboBox [doesn't have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_members.aspx) a SelectedItemProperty field, instead it is inheriting that from it's base class [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector_members.aspx).  Of course, Selector and ComboBox don't have all the properties that you could possibly bind to either, you'll have to traverse all the way back to [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_members.aspx) to find most of the inherited properties.

If you insert something to traverse the inheritance hierarchy then you can get all of the fields, and the validation rule will fire.

```
List<FieldInfo> dependencyPropertyFields = elementType.GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).ToList();

// Iterate through the fields defined on any base types as well
Type baseType = elementType.BaseType;
while (baseType != null)
{
    dependencyPropertyFields.AddRange(
        baseType.GetFields(
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));

    baseType = baseType.BaseType;
}
```